# Will address of `foo' here be always non-zero?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void foo(double);

int main(void) {
    // printf("address is: %p\n", *foo);

    if (foo)
        puts("indeed");
    else
        puts("not");
    exit(0);
}
```

It always compiles and prints `indeed` if line number 7 is commented but gcc warns me that:

```
the address of 'foo' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]
```

However, it doesn't compile if line 7 is uncommented:

```
/tmp/ccWvhcze.o: In function `main':
post.c:(.text.startup+0x5): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Well, if address is *always* non-zero according to gcc why does linking fail? Of course, I would expect it because `foo` is just not defined here but why does gcc claim that address will *always* be non-zero? Is it mandated by C standard for all identifiers in the translation unit to always evaluate to true?

Comment: `foo` is a pointer to a function, did you define it anywhere? You are dereferencing it. I don't know about the behavior of that.

Comment: The compiler simply optimizes away whatever it knows should evaluate to a constant condition. In this case,  it's warning you that it will optimize this code, and by the time linker comes into play, there are no references to `foo` anymore (as long as line 7 is commented).

Comment: `printf("address is: %p\n", (void *)foo);` or `printf("address is: %p, (void *)&foo);` provided that function pointers and void pointers are compatible (they aren't required to be, if I remember).

Comment: Note: It's allowed to be zero, it's just not allowed to be NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler removes the test in `if ()` because it's guaranteed to be true. Because of that the linker has nothing to resolve. Adding a `printf` of `foo` adds back the need to resolve foo.

Answer (score 8):

Testing `if (pointer_expression)` checks whether the pointer is a null pointer or not.  Every valid object and function is guaranteed to not be a null pointer.  (Note that a null pointer is not necessarily "zero".)

Comment: .... even if the linker didnt resolve it to anything. I wonder what the non null address points at?

Comment: if the linker did not resolve it to anything there will be no executable generated.   If it's dynamic linker scenario ( dll or so )  then you program simply won't start.   So in both cases this is not a valid question to ask

Answer (score 2):

You must remember that compilation and linking are two completely separate and independent phases for C programs. The compiler is saying "if (and only if) you link and execute this code, `foo` will always be non-zero". However, you then go on to attempt to link that object file into an executable without supplying a *definition* for `foo` (only a declaration). That's illegal, so linking fails. `foo` isn't NULL or not-NULL, it doesn't have a value.

Comment: The question was actually: Why does linking NOT fail when the only thing looking at `foo` is the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested because I'm writing this from my smartphone, I guess `foo` may become zero.

For example, linking with this NASM code will make `foo` zero if my thought is correct.

```
bits 32
absolute 0
global foo
global _foo
foo:
_foo:
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested this code with GCC 4.8.1 and NASM 2.11.08 and got output

```
address is: 00000000
indeed
```

Also, although this code is differ from the original, this code for [xv6](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public) on Ubuntu, GCC 4.6.3 ran on Vagrant VM

```
#include "types.h"
#include "user.h"

void foo(double a) {
    (void)a;
}

int main(void) {
    printf(1, "address is : %p\n", (void*)*foo);

    if (foo)
        printf(1, "indeed\n");
    else
        printf(1, "not\n");
    exit();
}
```

emitted output

```
address is : 0
indeed
```

(remove `-Werror` from the `CFLAGS` in xv6 `Makefile`, or you will get a compile error)

Also note that `*foo` becomes address of function `foo` because `foo` as operand of operator `*` is converted to a pointer to function `foo`, then dereferenced with `*` and becomes function `foo`, then converted to a pointer again for function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out the GCC assumes 'foo' will never be zero.  If you have function 'foo' then it will have some address,  if function foo is not defined then your program simply will not link and there will be no executable to run.   If you are linking to 'dll' or 'so' file that had function 'foo' at the time of linking, but later at the time of execution it was removed then your executable will not load.  So GCC safely assumes that 'foo' will never be zero.

However,  it is correct in 99.(99)% of the cases.  As MikeCat pointed out the function foo could be located at address zero.   This will never happen for user space executable or even the kernel code does not resort to such tricks.   The only practical programs that do play with putting objects at absolute addresses are boot loaders and other things that run directly on the hardware.

They rely on linker scripts to place objects at correct addresses.  Here is an example of code that does it technically yes,  but this is very sick thing to do.   The only C program I know that needs to resort to such tricks is boot loader code https://github.com/trini/u-boot/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-at91/armv7/u-boot-spl.lds

But,  even if boot loaders can do such thing,  GCC still might be correct.  Most of the CPUs or OSes reserve address '0' for some special purposes.  Most of the time the interrupt vector table is located there,  in other cases OS or Architecture itself reserves address 0 for null pointer so any attempt to access it will result in exception. I believe x86 protected mode, which is the mode in which all popular OSes (Linux, Windows) run user programs, is one of such architectures.

So GCC in your case GCC is probably correct at optimizing away the if statement, because you are using x86 version of gcc.  If you ever find the architecture where address 0 is not reserved,  it will most likely have a version of GCC that does not perform this type of optimization.

Comment: any attempt to access address 0 in x86 will result in exception? I disagree. 1. In real mode, address 0 is a part of interrupt vector and it should be accessble. 2. In [xv6](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public), which is an operating system for x86, address 0 is simply a part of user address space.

Comment: You right about real mode.  I haven't used it for very long time.